# Running A Shell Script Through A C++ app Started With JAVA

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu, sh

My requirement is to start a c++ application which runs some shell scripts in a certain folder. the c++ app is started with java.
The scripts its trying to run have being given chmod 777 access as well as the jar is started with sudo and the util is started with sudo from within the jar.

My problem is the scripts fail to run soemtimes saying script failed to run returned: 512 (the script is just an echo)
I am running all command line function in java using getRuntime.exec (I tried process builder too)
TLDR:
jar starts c++ app 
c++ app tries to run shell script
script fails sometimes
Anyone got any suggestions or faces similar situation ?

**EDIT 1** 
I should also mention that the scripts are being downloaded first via java. and then only passed on to the c++ app. The c++ utility works fine with scripts which are already there.I am using apache http client

Comment: 777 access on a script run with `sudo`?  Most important suggestion would be fix that access!  Other than that, need code before we can help.

Comment: You should've asked this as a C++ question, not Java. Also, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html for more info. Return value from a called application must be processed via appropriate macros to get the actual return code. My guess, the script hit a signal. Also, correct your `sudo` access as AJNeufeld notes.

Comment: The reason i asked it as a java question was caus the c++ app works fine independently with already available scripts. (check edit 1 :)). Also I fixed the sudo and 777 issue. now i dont run the jar or any commands with sudo basically. 
I think the problem maybe with the downloaded file.(using apache http client). Sorry if i have missunderstood anything very new to ubuntu and trying to understand all this sudo and chmod stuff.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer getting the proper error code helped me identify the actual problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed To Solve this there was a output stream that was still open while the c++ app was trying to access the scripts.